# change Preloader background color

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, preloader

I have a custom preloader that I designed in flash. When I load it in flex, it loads with a white background. When I try to change the background to black in my flash file & load it in Flex, the background color remains white. I've also tried to update the compiler settings in Flex, adding  "-default-background-color #000000" but I still get a white preloader background. I am using Flex 4. Here is my Pre.as file:
`

`

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://askmeflash.com/article/7/custom-preloader-progress-bar-flex) man solved it by adding background sprite and filling it with custom color you want.

And here http://iamjosh.wordpress.com/2007/12/18/flex-custom-preloader/ author also told that he added the compiler option like this:

> Finally, let’s change the background
>   color of the application to match our
>   logo a little better. Just add the
>   following Flex compiler argument:
>
> -default-background-color #FFFFFF

So, you might added this option to another one application you need instead.

**UPDATE 1**

Also look at this

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Change_Background_Color_of_the_Preloader_Phase-1421.html

And please, explain once again your goals, are you want to set color or something another, from preloader or parent application or whatever you want, just let me know.

**UPDATE 2**
And listen, if you really want some cool bg, you might do next thing.
1)Forget about preloader mechanism.
2)Write Your BG application
3)Add swfLoader overlay to your bg application
4)Draw progressbar for this container
5)Enjoy with 2 application architecture instead of standard way.

Questions!?

Comment: i don't see custom bg sprite in your preloader above. and post the code you tried, please. thanks.

Comment: lol, but would you mind to make some addChild to the stage? :)

Comment: did you asked how to setup color of preloader from application which use it?

Comment: so, if I am using a gradient color background in my main application, how do I set that in my preloader? Is there a better way to fill the entire background than just making a large rectangle like I have?

Comment: By doing the rectangle the way I have it, I noticed that sometimes when I run the preloader it will place a black rectangle on the left side of the page & a white rectangle on the right. It's like it got halfway through drawing the rectangle & then just gave up... there has to be a better way than this, right?

Comment: The code hasn't changed .... the part I am talking about is  cp.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
cp.graphics.drawRect(-1000,-1000,2000,2000)
cp.graphics.endFill(); ... is there a better way to set the background color?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.
solved it using opaqueBackground :

```
loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, init);

private function init(e:Event):void{
loader.opaqueBackground = 0x000000;
}
```

Worked great for me.